# How do I disable a Nvida GPU and use the Intel one instead?

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, intel-graphics

I have an MSI Z77A-GD55 mainboard with a Core i5-3570K CPU and integrated HD 4000 GPU. I also have a Nvidia GeForce GTX 560 GPU on PCIe.

I mainly use Ubuntu, but occasionally boot into Windows for gaming. Right now I have the HD 4000 disabled and only use the GTX 500 at all times. I would love to use the HD 4000 under Linux (nicer boot, less noise), but toggling it in the BIOS at every boot is cumbersome.

Is there a way to keep the GTX 500 on by default for Windows boots but disable it, when booting to Linux and use the HD 4000 instead?

Comment: If you are selecting this from BIOS, I don't think this is possible.

Comment: I hoped I could activate both in the BIOS settings and disable the NVIDIA card on my Linux desktop once it has started?

Comment: try nvdia prime for linux you can select for intel to use..

Answer (score 0):

If you install the propriatary drivers from Nvidia in Ubuntu, you can switch between graphics cards in the Nvidia control panel. This option can be found in the Nvidia PRIME tab in that control panel.